# Enable projects from msbuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Is there a way to enable projects on demand from msbuild?

I have these disabled projects that I like to build overnight on the build server.

```
>  msbuild solution.sln /t:Common.Test /p:Configuraion="Release" /p:Platform="x64"
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0
    [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
    Build started 03/11/2016 16:31:10.
    Project "soluton.sln" on node 1 (Common.Test target(s)).
    ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
      Building solution configuration "Debug|x64".
    ValidateProjects:
      The project "Common.Test" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Debug|x64".
    solution.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "Common.Test" does not exist in the project. [solution.sln]
    Done Building Project "solution.sln" (Common.Test target(s)) -- FAILED.


    Build FAILED.

    "solution.sln" (Common.Test target) (1) ->
      solution.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "Common.Test" does not exist in the project. [solution.sln]

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04
```

This is from VS2013 but I want to enable it on the Team Foundation Server 2015 build definition.

Comment: So you want to build "Common.Test" in TFS build but does not built it on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS Build definition, you can specify the projects you want to build in MSBuild task:

[image]

And you can trigger scheduled builds at the time you like:

[image]